# How to change URL from this ?name=title to ../title

Tags: php

I have a script, which automatically add a URL for every row I insert into database with php.

This is, how it works:

```
if (isset($_GET['name']) )
  $title = $_GET['name'];

 <Code to select and echo data from database here>
```

So, if I insert a row named "UserA", then a URL will be created like this:

```
example.com/users/?name=UserA
```

I want to remove `"?name="`and make the URL like: `example.com/users/UserA`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess`

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /users/(.*)$ /users/name=$1`

If you manage the server yourself, be sure to enable `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Is this is what you mean? http://prntscr.com/fhaazz

Yes mod_rewrite is enabled. But it is not working

Comment: If your URL is like https://example.com/users/?name=example then you should remove the /website part in the `RewriteRule` if it starts with /website then you should add that to the second part as well.

Comment: I am using it inside xampp, so /website is necessary. The URL is more like localhost/website/users

Comment: Yeah use `RewriteRule /website/users/(.*)$ /website/users/name=$1`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fhafsg

Not working bro.Wait, let me confirm once again, if mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: https://www.leonardaustin.com/blog/technical/enable-mod_rewrite-in-xampp/

Comment: This should work. I think it's a problem with XAMPP. What happens if you go to the url /website/users/UserA will it give an error?

Comment: Error 404 page bro

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with `. htaccess` then it's good, else create a file in your project folder called `.htaccess` where `htaccess` is it's extension not a name:

Then put this into the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^users/([0-9A-Za-z]+)/?$    users.php?name=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product requests
```

This will enable a url rewrite rule and redirect request from `users/name` to `users.php` file where you can manage all the request.

**Now** by going through the url as `users/name` you will be able to show data from database about that user within the file `users.php`:

**Note:** `.htaccess` file is an APACHE server configuration file.